# Export All query results to one file vs separate in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

I am querying hundreds of different databases and wondering if there is anyway to export the results into one file vs one file per result. The result view is appended into one tab and I was hoping "export all" meant all results into one file vs hundreds of files. Is this simply because I am querying different databases or is there a workaround? Most solutions I've read about are for exporting for back up and not results of a query. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You've worded the question assuming (what I assume is) a phpmyadmin interface. Can you write a script and not use phpmyadmin? Is it the same query on all databases and some generated `select ... into outfile from db.tbl1 .. union all select db2.tbl1 ...` is suitable? What is the actual form of the query and expected file contents?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance as I'm new to this. I am not using an interface but it sounds like writing a script is the way to go. My task was to count active items of certain types across all databases. Each query result contained the count in a separate file, and for the sake of ease and reporting I wanted all results in one file.

Comment: "I am not using an interface" ... well, you mention tabs and an "export all" function, so you seem to be using some graphical user interface (GUI) application to access the database, and so the question is about this specific tool / interface?